# How to use zxing in Android and let zxing handle the results internally

Tags: android, zxing

a short example:

I am scanning a qr code like "WIFI:S:The SSID;;" with the Barcode Scanner app and it successfully handles the scan result internally and opens the wifi settings.

When i am using the zxing library via Intent integration from within my own app i get the result back in onActivityResult. Now i have the text of the scanned code, but i have to handle it all by myself.

But the logic is already there, why should I implement it again? Can i somehow tell the zxing library to handle scan results internally?

Goddchen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just launch the Barcode Scanner app then, also via Intent. There's no need to wait for the reply if you don't want to handle the reply. The only problem is that the user has to come back to your app themselves.

Or you can parse the result using the `ResultParser` code in your own app, and lift the code for `WifiResultHandler` to make the changes to the wi-fi network in your app. It's not much code to copy and repurpose.

Comment: Hey Sean, thanks for the quick reply. The "problem" is that i want to handle some kind of scan results, and some should be handled by zxing. Thanks for pointing out the ResultParser and ResultHandler codes, those work perfectly! :)